# RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1 Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Я здесь уже спрашивал, как соединить два списка между собой, если их оба нужно отфильтровать по тайтлам, при этом у них нет общего айди. Сейчас я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы при переходе на другую страницу отображались отфильтрованные элементы, принадлежащие каждому магазину.

В ответ получаю вот такую ошибку - `RangeError (index): Index out of range: index should be less than 1: 1`, при этом сам элемент отфильтрован и показывается на экране правильно. Как можно это избежать?

На скринах, что я имею ввиду:

[image: стартовый экран со всеми кафе][image: Второй экран, где есть уже нужный элемент, но с ошибкой]

Код с 1 страницы:

```
List<Coffee> uniteCoffee(List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop, List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu){
      if(coffeeShop.length != coffeeShop.length) return [];

      List<Coffee> temp = <Coffee>[];

      for(int i = 0; i<coffeeShop.length; i++) {
        temp.add(Coffee(coffeeShop[i], coffeeMenu[i]));
      }

      return temp;
    }
    final List<Coffee> coffee = uniteCoffee(coffeeShop, coffeeMenu);

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(itemCount: coffee.length,itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(coffee[index].shop.shopTitle),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Exp1(
                     shopMenuTitle: coffee[index].menu.shopMenuTitle,
                    )));
```

Код со 2ой

```
Exp1({Key key, this.shopMenuTitle, this.coffee}) : super(key: key);

  List<CoffeeShopMenu> get coffeeMenuTitle => coffeeMenu.where((element) => element.shopMenuTitle == shopMenuTitle).toList();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  List<Coffee> uniteCoffee(List<CoffeeShop> coffeeShop, List<CoffeeShopMenu> coffeeMenu){
    if(coffeeShop.length != coffeeShop.length) return [];

    List<Coffee> temp = <Coffee>[];

    for(int i = 0; i<coffeeShop.length; i++) {
      temp.add(Coffee(coffeeShop[i], coffeeMenu[i]));
    }

    return temp;
  }
  final List<Coffee> coffee = uniteCoffee(coffeeShop, coffeeMenu);

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(itemCount: coffee.length,itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(coffeeMenuTitle[index].shopMenuTitle),
        );
      }),
    );
```

Comment: Размер `coffee` и `coffeeMenuTitle` разный... Проблема тут: `itemCount: coffee.length`

Comment: Вы получили `coffeeMenuTitle` через `where`, то есть, отбросили все не нужное что не подходит по условию. По этому его размер стал меньше чем размер `coffee`.

Comment: Спасибо @MiT глаза совсем замылились вчера, очевидного не увидел. Все решалось так просто.

Comment: Тогда лучше закрыть вопрос.